# Select SQL logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Folks at a loss here!!! 
First, this is what I am trying to achieve:

---

Select all the records from table CUSTOMER_ORDER_DETAILS table shown below and if multiple entries for the same CUSTOMER_NO exist then:
- select the entry with PAID = 1 
- if there are multiple PAID = 1 entries, then select the record with TYPE = Y

[image: Table]

Expected Result:
877, CU115, lit,    0, 1, X 
878, CU111, Toi, 1, 1, Y 
879, CU117,  Fla, 1, 1, X

My approach was to get the count(CUSTOMER_NO) > 1 using GROUP BY on CUSTOMER_NO, but as soon as I am adding the remaining columns of the table to the Select statement, the count column is showing a value of 1.
Any pointers to tackle this or implement if-else kind of logic?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: the easiest solution is to dissect your logic and combine them try that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  Here is one method to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_no
                                order by paid desc, type desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This assumes that `paid` takes on the values 0 and 1, and that `type` has the values `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the help. Going to read on prioritization query a bit. Would you mind explaining the logic a little bit? This might help others as well.

Comment: @user1195192 . . . Run the subquery and you will see what happens.  The rows that you want end up with `seqnum` as "1".

Answer (score 1):

You can prioritize these conditions with an `order by` condition in `row_number` function.

```
select * from (
select t.*,
row_number() over(partition by customer_no 
                  order by case when paid=1 and type='Y' then 1
                                when paid=1 then 2 
                                else 3 end) as rnum
from customer_orders t
) t 
where rnum=1
```

- This assumes there can only be one row with type='Y' per customer_no if there exist multiple rows with paid=1 for that same customer_no.
- If there exist multiple rows with paid =1 and all of them have a type <> 'Y' then a row is arbitrarily picked amongst them.

Comment: vkp, thanks a lot. Would you mind explaining the logic a little bit? This might help others as well

Comment: @user1195192 .. i suggest you experiment with different `order by` conditions in `row_number` and you'll get to know how this query works.